# Which maturity date do yields refer to?

Tags: yield

I notice that [here](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/pages/TextView.aspx?data=yield) the current yields of different treasuries are reported each day. However, are there multiple maturity dates for each security with probably different yields?

For example, consider a 10 year note issued in 2015 and a 10 year note issued last month. The yields of these two may be different based on their prices, but yet a single yield is reported.

1. How is this single yield number computed? Does it just take the most recently issued 10 year note?
2. Are there data sources which split the 10 year notes by maturity date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually underneath [here](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yield), it gives the methodology on how the yield is computed. It plots yields against current time to maturity. Then they fit a cubic spline and read off the standard maturity points: 1, 2, 3 and 6 months and 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 20, and 30 years.

This way, even if no notes exist with a full 10-years to maturity, a 10-year yield can be read off.